# How to get style attribute of DOM node using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

I have the following component:

```
// Styled component.
export const StyledBtn = styled.button`
    height: ${( height ) => height};
`;

// Functional component.
const Btn = ({ height }) => <StyledBtn height={height} />;

export default Btn;
```

I want to be able to check that the actual height (in the DOM) is what was passed to the `Btn` component (I do not want to check the prop value). This is how I would envisage the test looking:

```
test('button renders at the correct height', () => {
    const btn = mount(<Btn height={20});
    const node = findDOMNode(btn);
    const height = node.getAttribute('height');
    expect(height).toEqual('20');
});
```

But, the test fails:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      "20"
    Received:
      null
```

Any ideas how to test this?

Comment: I think your code for `Btn` is wrong. You're passing the props to the `height` attribute. It should be:

`const Btn = props => <StyledBtn height={props.height} />;`

Comment: yup, sorry, my mistake I have edited the question to show the correct syntax. The problem still exists with the correct code.

Comment: is there a `.props()` function like there is in Enzyme? You could do  `.props().style` if so

Comment: Tried `btn.find('button').props().style` but this is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the library `jest-styled-components`. Also, the `mount()` function is mounting the functional component, so you then need to `find` the styled component within it:

```
import 'jest-styled-components';
...
test('button renders at the correct height', () => {
    const component = mount(<Btn height={20});
    const btn = component.find('button');
    expect(btn).toHaveStyleRule('height', '20px');
});
```